# Opening tournament strategy for Texas Hold'em

Tags: texas-hold-em

I am about to enter my first deep stack tournament. The structure is 1 rebuy and 1 reentry up until the fourth round of a 22 round tournament. Is it better to start off aggressively while the blinds are low or start conservatively and wait until after the rebuy and reentry period is closed?
This card room is home to many wild card aggressive players.

Comment: I'd decide on that based on your table. Just get a feel for the players at your table, learn who's agressive, and who isn't. Abuse that knowledge. If the aggressive player folds, you have a mediocre hand & the tight players are behind you, go for an open. It just depends on the players.

Answer (score 1):

Dnegs used to flood his table with chips when you could rebuy at the same table so he could try to win them all back. having a lot of chips early is a huge advantage. Most rebuys you don't end up at the same table.

The best tournament strategy is to try to build a stack early and focus on preservation later in the tournament when you get near the money bubble.

if you just try to play ABC poker the whole time waiting for "good" hands you will blind yourself out and find yourself constantly having to fold to more aggressive players. You don't make hands very often so it often goes to the person who bets first.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should play tight pre-ante, because there really is no incentive to open up a lot of hands, since the pot you could win is really small. Hand like low-mid pairs should be folded in early position and hands like 89o should be folded on the button. When the ante kicks in you want to loosen up a bit. Depending on the stacks around the table you want to open more hands relative to pre-ante. If you open into stacks less than 20 BB you want to be a bit tighter, since they can re-jam on you and often you cannot call. If you feel like the player in the big blind is weak, you can open more wide, but don't get too crazy. Remember, in tournaments every chip you lose is more valuable than a chip that you win. Survival is key, so play a conservative style, especially in the micro stakes. (For free entry tournaments) you can play more aggresive because a lot of players sitting out at the early stage :)

Answer (score 0):

Not aggressive early. In a tournament you want to stay alive.

You want to stay away from coin flips especially for all in. Say you are forced to call a coin flip for all in early on.  Knowing you have a rebuy gives you the option to call a coin flip once.  You will probably need to call a coin flip more than once and get lucky - still not something you want to do.

There was a tournament where Daniel Negreanu was going all almost every hand and just rebuy.  But he probably had some side action that made that favorable.  And he has a deep bankroll.

I assume the rebuy is the same price.